# Open external link in cocos2dx 3.0

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using

```
Application::getInstance()->openURL("www.google.com");
```

But it gives error that there is no method"opnURL".

Can anybody please help?

Comment: The **Application** Class has no `openURL()` member function [API Ref](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.2/db/de2/classcocos2d_1_1_application.html), What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 3):

I am using the latest cocos2d version. This method works fine for me:

```
CCApplication::getInstance()->openURL("http://www.google.com");
```

Edit:
   CCApplication is deprecated, so use:

```
Application::getInstance()->openURL("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: If you're using a new version of cocos2d-x 3.+ It's not necessary using the **CCAplication** just use **Application**

Answer (score 0):

I can't find that method on the Application class:

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.2/db/de2/classcocos2d_1_1_application.html

But you could read this reference:

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/opening-urls-in-external-browser/2642

And implement in a native code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how old of a version you were working with but in the latest stable version,  3.5, that method [is implemented](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.5/db/de2/classcocos2d_1_1_application.html#ab2b29142ec04204db57220b92d7bc65f) and should work as expected.